# Angularjs - Reset form fields, model and validations

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I am developing project in MEAN STACK, I want to reset my form and model's variable.
I can reset validation but value of form field can not reset when fields value is dirty means not valid validation.
When field has not any error then this field will be reset properly.

> Signup.html

```
<div class="tabs-frame-content tab_content" id="tab2" ng-controller="SignupCtrl">
<div id="user_signup">
    <form name="frmSignup" id="frmSignup" ng-submit="doRegistration(frmSignupSubmitted && frmSignup.$valid)" autocomplete="off" novalidate="">
        <div class="content">
            <label class="formlabel1">Fullname</label>
            <input type="text" name="txtFullname" id="txtFullname" class="inputbox inputbox_width" ng-model="user.txtFullname" required="">
            <div class="error_msg" ng-show="(frmSignup.txtFullname.$touched || frmSignupSubmitted) && frmSignup.txtFullname.$error.required">Fullname is required</div>

            <label class="formlabel1">Nickname</label>
            <input type="text" name="txtNickname" id="txtNickname" class="inputbox inputbox_width" ng-model="user.txtNickname" ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/" required="" hz-unique-nick-name>
            <div class="error_msg" ng-show="(frmSignup.txtNickname.$touched || frmSignupSubmitted) && frmSignup.txtNickname.$error.required">Nickname is required</div>
            <div class="error_msg" ng-show="!frmSignup.txtNickname.$error.nick_name && !frmSignup.txtNickname.$error.required && frmSignup.txtNickname.$error.hzUniqueNickName && !frmSignup.txtNickname.$error.pattern">NickName has already been taken</div>
            <div class="error_msg" ng-show="(frmSignup.txtNickname.$touched || frmSignupSubmitted) && frmSignup.txtNickname.$error.pattern">Nickname must be alphanumeric</div>

            <label class="formlabel1">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" class="inputbox inputbox_width" ng-model="user.txtEmail" required="" ng-email="" hz-unique-email="">
            <div class="error_msg" ng-show="(frmSignup.txtEmail.$touched || frmSignupSubmitted) && frmSignup.txtEmail.$error.required">Email is required</div>
            <div class="error_msg" ng-show="(frmSignup.txtEmail.$touched || frmSignupSubmitted) && frmSignup.txtEmail.$error.email">Email is invalid</div>
            <div class="error_msg" ng-show="!frmSignup.txtEmail.$error.email && !frmSignup.txtEmail.$error.required && frmSignup.txtEmail.$error.hzUniqueEmail">Email has already been taken</div>

            <label class="formlabel1">Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" class="inputbox inputbox_width" ng-model="user.txtPassword" required="" ng-pattern="/^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,})$/">
            <div class="error_msg" ng-show="(frmSignup.txtPassword.$touched || frmSignupSubmitted) && frmSignup.txtPassword.$error.required">Password is required</div>
            <div class="error_msg" ng-show="(frmSignup.txtPassword.$touched || frmSignupSubmitted) && frmSignup.txtPassword.$error.pattern">8 Characters or longer and contain at least one number(0-9), one uppercase(A-Z), one smallcase (a-z), one digit (0-9) and one symbol (?=.*[@#$%])</div>

            <label class="formlabel1">Confirm password</label>
            <input type="text" name="txtConfirmPassword" id="txtConfirmPassword" class="inputbox inputbox_width" ng-model="user.txtConfirmPassword" required="" hz-compare-password="frmSignup.txtPassword">
            <div class="error_msg" ng-show="(frmSignup.txtConfirmPassword.$touched || frmSignupSubmitted) && frmSignup.txtConfirmPassword.$error.required">Confirm password is required</div>
            <div class="error_msg" ng-show="(frmSignup.txtConfirmPassword.$touched || frmSignupSubmitted) && (frmSignup.txtConfirmPassword.$error.hzComparePassword && !frmSignup.txtConfirmPassword.$error.required)">Confirm password must same as password</div>
        </div>
        <div class="actions button-groups login-button-space">
            <input type="button" value="Reset" name="btnCancelSignup" id="btnCancelSignup" class="popup-modal-dismiss submit-btn button pull-right sp1" ng-model="user.btnCancel" ng-click="Reset()">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-btn button pull-right sp1" ng-click="frmSignupSubmitted = true" />
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

> signupController.js

```
(function () {
'use strict'
function SignupCtrl($scope, $location, $rootScope, $window, $timeout, UserService, notifications) {

    $scope.Reset = function(){
        $scope.user= angular.copy({});
        $scope.frmSignup.$setPristine();
        $scope.frmSignup.$setUntouched();
        $scope.frmSignupSubmitted = false;
        //reset active tab
        //for close magnific popup
        $.magnificPopup.instance.close();
    };
}

angular
     .module('AppWhizbite')
     .controller('SignupCtrl', [SignupCtrl]);
}());
```

> Issue

```
Error : When email entered *laxmantest* in email field ,click on reset button validation reseted but models $scope.user.txtEmail will not rest and it will stay displayed in email field.

Work proper : When email entered *laxmantest@mailinator.com* in email field ,click on reset button all works fine.
```

can anybody help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You could try and set  $scope.frmSignup="" in the reset function

Comment: Using $scope.frmSignup="" in reset function,  "Error: elCPassword_ is undefined" error occurred